# Setting array elements without knowing their index

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search array keys and return the index of matched key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782245/search-array-keys-and-return-the-index-of-matched-key)

In my code I'm doing `$params[ltrim($part, ':')] = null;` in order to get an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [random] => 
    [something] => 
)
```

I need a way of setting the values for each element sequentially without knowing its index. In this example, index `0` would be `id`, `1` would be `random` and so on. I tried setting it using `0` and `1` anyway and ended up with an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [lol] => 
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
)
```

is there a way I can do this? Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `foreach` to iterate over the array?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `foreach` to iterate through an associative array

```
<?php

foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    $arr[$key] = "some value";
}

/*
Array
(
    [id] => some value
    [random] => some value
    [something] => some value
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to your `$params` array (which you already created), create a `$values` array with the values indexed as you need or have them. Then just combine:

```
$final = array_combine(array_keys($params), $values);
```

If you create the `$params` array firsthand with those names as values instead of keys, you can even spare the `array_keys` call.